# LoopBack with Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, loopbackjs

I am trying to run a LoopBack server with ionic client, but I am getting the "Error: Cannot GET /cordova.js" error.

My code can be cloned from github at: https://github.com/giladba/BetterTrader2.git

Problem description:

I created a LoopBack application, and at the client directory I created an Ionic tabs application.

After that, I ran these commands on the client directory:

ionic platform add android

ionic build android

In server/middleware.json I redirected the index.html folder to the Ionic www folder like so:

```
"files": {

"loopback#static": {
  "params": "$!../client/www"
}
```

but when I run `node .` I get cordova.js not found when I open http://localhost:3000/ in the browser:

[image]

note that even though there is an exception the application seems to be working fine.
Any idea how I can fix the exception?

Answer (score 2):

Cordova gets injected into the app when deployed on a mobile device.  When you use the `ionic serve` command locally, for example, cordova.js always 404s.  You don't need it unless you're on a mobile device in a cordova app, and it will be deployed automatically in that case.

Comment: So why am i getting this exception on the server side? cordova is running only on the client.

Comment: and by the way, when i run ionic serve i never get this exception

Comment: During development, Ionic tries to load the cordova.js file from the root of the web server.  So, it is likely hitting your loopback instance and loopback cannot find the file, so it errors out.

Comment: Is there something like "try-catch" in java that i can add somewhere to not show that error?